# How to access a C# internal property from VB.NET project in same solution?

Tags: c#, vb.net

My Visual Studio 2008 solution contains both C# and VB.NET projects.  From a VB.NET project, how can I access a C# property with its access modifier set to "internal"?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to make the assembly's friends with the [InternalsVisibleTo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0tke9fxk.aspx) attribute.

Assuming that you don't sign your assemblies, it's as easy as adding an assembly level InternalsVisibleTo attribute to the C# project with the name of the VB.Net assembly.  Typically you do this in AssemblyInfo.cs (under the Properties folder)

```
[assembly:InternalsVisibleTo("MyVbAssemblyName")]
```

Comment: Here's an SO link discussing this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/171332/accessing-internal-members-via-system-reflection

Comment: Thanks.  Works great between C# and VB.NET.  It looks like there's no good way to make my C# internals visible to ASP.NET though.  That's not a huge problem for me though.