# How to use System.Web.UI.Page.DecryptString(String s)?

Tags: .net, asp.net, encryption

I saw with Reflector a very interesting method in System.Web.UI.Page : DecryptString(String s).

But it is a "internal static method", so how can I use it ? (I dont find it in msdn doc)

Thanks a lot !

Comment: I believe that is used for ViewStates, and uses the Machine Key for encryption.

Comment: Yes but How can I use it to encrypt whatever string I want to encrypt ?

Answer (score 1):

As its marked as internal it is only intended to be called from code that resides in the same assembly. However this is just a guideline and you can use reflection to execute this method. Be careful though as this method might change in a future version of asp.net and break your code.

See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/171332/accessing-internal-members-via-system-reflection) for some sample code on how to execute internal methods.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to look at [`ProtectedData`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.protecteddata.aspx) I think that will do what you want to do. To do strings you just need to convert the string in to a byte array and the reverse when you decrypt.